# Java service architecture

Tags: java, architecture

I want to design an API which reads a large text file, extracts the relevant info and returns a list of Foo objects like this:

```
interface FooService {
    Optional<Foo> getFoo(Bar bar);
}
```

The format of the text file and the way it is parsed is always the same. The only thing that can vary is the location of the file, i.e. it could be a file on the local system or an URL. So I created an AbstractFooService:

```
class AbstractFooService implements FooService {

    Map<Bar, Foo> registry;

    AbstractFooService(InputStream is) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            registry = reader.lines()
                .map(l -> l.split(';'))
                .map(a -> new Foo(a[0]), a[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    } 

    Optional<Foo> getFoo(Bar bar) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(registry.get(bar));
    }
}
```

Concrete implementations would just call the super constructor with an InputStream:

```
class UrlFooService extends AbstractFooService {
    UrlFooService(String url) {
        super(createStream(url));
    }

    private static InputStream createStream(final String url) {
        try {
            return new URL(string).openStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Is that a sound API design or is there a 'better' way to achieve my goal? I.e. is it smart to call the super constructor with an InputStream or would it be better to have a separate `load()` method that opens the stream when needed?

Comment: For working code, please turn to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Doing work in a constructor is generally a bad idea. It makes for difficult to test code and can result in non-obvious behaviour in inheritance hierarchies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need that abstract base class there. Preferring composition over inheritance; I think the more reasonable solution would be to have:

```
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService { 
...
```

And then clients such as

```
public class UrlFooService implements FooService {
  private final FooService delegatee;

 public  UrlFooService(URL url) {
    delegate = new FooServiceImpl(url.openStream())
 ...
 @Override
 Optional<Foo> getFoo(Bar bar) { return delegatee.getFoo(bar); }
```

Inheritance couples your concrete service classes with that parent class; I would prefer to avoid, by using this simple "delegatee" mechanism.

Please note: I also changed the ctor of the UrlSerivce to take a URL. You already have the types there, so why bother to call new yourself? That just means that your UrlService would have to deal with all the things that could go wrong there!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of challenges with your question here and I would start by breaking down the problem a little differently.

As @sisyphus said, watch out for those things you're doing in the constructor.  A constructor really should be focused on just creating a "valid object" and nothing more.  Many good ideas from @GhostCat too.

Instead think of modeling the problem as follows:

Create an interface that represents the API for your service.  In this case if you want it to be "getFoo()" then great.  Consider what you would want to pass (is it really the file or a URL or path).  Since you said it was a big file, it might not be a great idea to instantiate a big object in memory that you're going to be parsing again into a useful format.  You'll definitely pay the price in garbage collection.

Next you should think of separating out the "finding" of the file - or opening the stream with the parsing logic.  There are plenty of exceptions that can occur when simply trying to open the file - from it not being found, to not having permissions, to having too many open files (ulimit).

When it comes to parsing, I would suggest that you consider to get really clear on what you are parsing and for what.  If this is a real-world problem, 'stable formats' are always subject to change - especially when it comes to tolerating 'invalid' formats - like the existence of other non-printable characters or an unexpected EOF.  There will be a lot of demands to handle things gracefully and also a need to understand the stats of what was parsed, what had errors and how to handle that.

My 2 cents.